# Equivalent definitions of group action, isomorphism of GSet categories

Tags: category-theory, group-actions, equivariant-maps

***Context:*** 
For group actions on a set, there are two habitual definitions and a bijection between objects from each definition:

1. A function $G\times A \rightarrow A$ with the usual properties
2. A group morphism $G\rightarrow Aut_{set}(A)=S_{A}$

We can then define two categories $GSet$ of group actions where objects respectively follow the precedent definitions. Morphisms, which correspond to equivariant functions, are defined in each category as respecting the following commutative diagrams:

1. For the first definition:$$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   G\times A @>{\rho_A}>>A\\
   @VVV \circlearrowleft @VVV \\
   G\times A' @>{\rho_{A'}}>> A'
   \end{CD}$$
2. and for the second one: $\color{red}{\textbf{edit: }\text{as noted by Jules Essuie-Glace and Jendrik Stelzner, this definition is wrong.}}$ 
   $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   S_A @>{\phi}>>S_{A'}\\
   @AAA \circlearrowleft @AAA \\
   G  @= G
   \end{CD}$$

***Questions:***
Intuitively, there should be an isomorphism between the two categories. The object part of such a functor is clear but I can't build the morphism part. Does such an isomorphism exist? Is more categorical formalism (such as viewing group actions as functors) necessary to have a more elegant formulation?

***My attempt:***
Informally, we have this diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\{\text{1st-definition actions}\} @>\text{some 1st-Def equivariant morphism}>>\{\text{1st-definition actions}\}\\
@|  @| \\
\{\text{2nd-definition actions}\}  @>\text{some 2st-Def equivariant morphism}>> \{\text{2nd-definition actions}\}
\end{CD}$$
Therefore, by denoting $\sigma$ the object bijection between 1st and 2nd definition actions, if $r$ and $s$ are the two equivariant morphisms, we should have:
$$r = \phi \circ s \circ \phi^{-1}$$
I don't exactly know what types of objects to look for the following diagram to make sense. I've tried going to sets for one direction, but I keep getting mixed up in formalism and losing track of what type of objects I'm dealing with. For example, from a morphism $S_A\xrightarrow{\phi}S_{A'}$, we have by definition $\phi(id_A) = id_{A'}$. As sets, $id_A$ and $id_{A'}$ are the diagonals $A \mathrel{\tilde{=}}\Delta_A \subseteq A\times A$ and $A'\mathrel{\tilde{=}}\Delta_{A'} \subseteq A'\times A'$ and we obtain from $\phi$ a function $\hat{\phi}:A \rightarrow A'$. I am not able to show anything about it as I am not sure how to transfer equivariance of $\phi$ into the second category. Surely some language problem is happening. Similar problems arise for me in the second direction.

Comment: Use the functor $\hom_{Grp} (G, \mathfrak{S}(\bullet))$ for your second definition :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was unclear in my initial post but the crux of the issue is that I'm unable to see what the morphism part of $hom_{grp}(G, S_{\cdot})$ is. Even after quite some thought, I can't really make sense of it.

Comment: If you want to construct your category isomorphism, first try to understand how G action morphism work, you can then find an explicit iso

Comment: The core of the problem is that the second definition is wrong. It defines _something_, but not equivariant maps from $A$ to $A'$.

Comment: Thank you both. I didn't have a concrete definition (I'm studying aluffi chapter 0 and no explicit definition is given for the second case) and inferred that was the one. I will come back with a fleshed out answer.

Comment: One way of understanding why your second definition is wrong is because while $G\times A\to A$ naturally corresponds to $G\to S^A$, and similarly for $A'$, these are components for the adjunctions $(-)\times A \dashv \text{hom}(A,-)$ and $(-)\times A' \dashv \text{hom}(A',-)$ , which are unrelated.

Comment: (i.e. the adjunction is not on the $G$ entry)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I wrongly modelled the second definition after some sort of under-category. Though the objects of the categories are correct, objects in the second category are maps $f:A\rightarrow A'$ such that $f(g\cdot )=g\cdot f$. I will add a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by the gentlemen in the comments, the second definition for morphisms is wrong. In fact, the morphisms should be maps $f:A \rightarrow A'$ such that, with $\sigma_A :G \rightarrow S_A$ and $\sigma_{A'}:G\rightarrow S_{A'}$ the action morphisms and denoting  $\sigma_g(\cdot)=\sigma_A(g)(\cdot)$, $\sigma'_g(\cdot)=\sigma_{A'}(g)(\cdot)$, we have:
$$\forall g \in G, f\circ \sigma_g(\cdot)=\sigma'_g \circ f(\cdot)$$
which corresponds, with abuse of notation $g\cdot f = \sigma'_g(f)$ and $f(g\cdot)=f(\sigma_g(\cdot))$, to the commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>f>> A'\\
@V g\cdot V V \circlearrowleft @VV g\cdot V\\
A @>>f> A'
\end{CD}$$
Similarly, the equivariant condition for the 1st definition means that, with the same notations as the initial post, we have:
$$\rho_{A'}(g,f(\cdot))=f(\rho_A(g, \cdot))$$
We have already established that we have a bijection between 1st and 2nd definition objects. Now, define $\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}$ that respectively send  objects from the 2nd definition category to the 1st and vice versa. It is immediate that they are bijective on objects and therefore we have preimages for both cases which will be denoted with the pairs $\sigma_A -\rho_A$. For morphisms, we define $\mathscr{F}(f)=\mathscr{G}(f)=f$. In one direction ,we have:
$$\rho_{A'}( \mathscr{F}(f))=\mathscr{F}(\sigma_{A'}) \circ \mathscr{F}(f)=\mathscr{F}(\sigma_{A'} \circ f)=\mathscr{F}(f\circ\sigma_A)=\mathscr{F}(f)\circ \mathscr{F}(\sigma_A) = \mathscr{F}(f) \circ \rho_A$$
Hence $\mathscr{F}(f)$ is indeed equivariant. The opposite direction follows the exact same proof. Skipping some detail, we see that $\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}$ are indeed functors that preserve equivariant maps from one definition to the other and that they are inverse to each other, providing us with the wanted isomorphism.